# How can I convert this vbs into a batch file?

Tags: vbscript

Here is the code:

`Set sapi=Createobject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak ("Preparing your file now...")`

I want to insert it into a batch file with other codes in it. It would be something like this;

```
Start google chrome
Open a new command prompt tab
Go to stack overflow
*Set sapi=Createobject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak ("Please subscribe to AstralWolf")*
```

How can I make that code VBS - Batch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like that by the easy way when you call it as a function : `Call:Speak "<your message goes here>"`

```
@echo off
Start "" chrome.exe "www.stackoverflow.com"
Call:Speak "Please subscribe to AstralWolf"
exit /b
::**********************************************
:Speak <msg>
(
    echo Set sapi=Createobject("sapi.spvoice"^)
    echo sapi.Speak("%~1"^)
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::**********************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do it is to create a temp vbs file and run it from bat file. Sample batch file code would be something like the below

```
@echo off
cd %temp%
echo set varSAPI=WScript.CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") >> "tmp.vbs"
echo varSAPI.Speak "Please subscribe to AstralWolf" >> "tmp.vbs"
start tmp.vbs
pause
del tmp.vbs
@echo on
exit /b
```

Edit - As per @Ansgar Wiechers's suggestion, I am using temp folder.

Comment: Using a temp file is the only way I can see, since batch doesn't provide API access. I'd create the file in `%TEMP%`, though, since write access to the current working directory (or the script directory) isn't always guaranteed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - I assumed that if OP has rights to execute a script from a particular folder, he may also have rights to file manipulations as well. But I totally agree with your suggestion as it would not only hide the temp script, but is almost certain to be created in temp folder.

Comment: @PankajJaju Thanks! Working like a blast!

Comment: @AidenTooMLG - Happy to help. Don't forget to mark it as [**Accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cscript yourscript.vbs
```

Paste it into a batch, it will open it.
To hide the VBS, right-click, properties, and check "Hidden". If you had it on, in Control Panel, untick "Show Hidden Icons".