# Giant image covering desktop? (Batch File)

Tags: image, batch-file

Is it possible to have an image that covers the entire desktop?

Now when I say desktop, I am referring to the whole entire computer screen, not the background. It would stay on their screen for an amount of time before disappearing. Here is the image I want to be covered on the screen, [click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9u6f.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you want to make a prank to your friends !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based from ***@npocmaka***

Just give a shout and tell me the result :

***Prank.bat***

```
<!-- :
@echo off
mshta.exe "%~f0" %*
exit /b
rem 
--> 
<html>
<hta:application id="oHTA"
<HTA:APPLICATION    
BORDER="none"  
INNERBORDER="no"  
CAPTION="no"  
SYSMENU="no"  
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"  
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"  
ICON="NO"  
SCROLL="No"  
SCROLLFLAT="yes"  
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"  
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"  
SHOWINTASKBAR="no"  
CONTEXTMENU="no"  
SELECTION="no"/> 
<head>
<style>
body {
color:black;
background-color:black;
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/idG7OEJ.png);
background-position:center center;
}
</style>
</head>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad()
    Call Kill("explorer.exe")
    idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:ExecuteMyScript()",5000)
end sub
'****************************************************
Sub ExecuteMyScript()
    window.close
    Call RunExplorer()
End Sub
'****************************************************
Sub Kill(Process)
    Dim Ws,Command,Execution
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "& Process &""
    Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,True)
    Set Ws = Nothing
End Sub 
'****************************************************
Sub RunExplorer()
    Dim Ws
    Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    ws.run "explorer.exe"
End Sub
'****************************************************
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Looks awesome xD. Can I make it all go away after like 5 seconds? It goes away then stays as a black screen.

Comment: @AidenTooMLG First you should accept an anwser here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824508/how-can-i-convert-this-vbs-into-a-batch-file

Second i don't understand what did you mean ?

Comment: Well, when it is run, it shows what I want, then it disappears and shows a black screen. Run it for your self. If it happens to you, just to Ctrl + Alt + Del and Sign out. Sign in again and it fixes. How could I fix this?

Comment: @AidenTooMLG What did you mean by fix and sign in and sign out ??
 can you provide me more details and what's your main aim and what did you expected as result for you ?

Comment: So I want that image to cover the screen for 5 seconds, then I want it to disappear and return to the original screen.

Comment: @AidenTooMLG Yes, this what happen for this code ? it cover the hole sceen with your image for 5 secondes and close it after that ! so you didn't test it yet ?
So if you want to change the timeout from 5000ms=5s to 10000ms=10s or 30000ms=30s and so on .....

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. How'd about you test it out and let me know what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120591/discussion-between-hackoo-and-aidentoomlg).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [**example**](https://gist.github.com/npocmaka/cfdda5c11fdd1edc1281165d7b61110a). Decided to embed the picture as base64 string (you can encode a picture in base 64 and put in the source) . In this case it will close after 5 seconds but if you comment out this line `idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 5000)` it will stay until the mshta PID is killed. Though I don't know if it is possible to cover the taskbar too (with hta application.I know how to do it with .net/C# app).

Comment: Ok, how about changing the background on your desktop. Could I make it change for 10 seconds then revert back to its original background? Again in batch :).

Comment: @AidenTooMLG - yes  but this is a completely different question. The background image is stored in the registry so you can do it easily with `REG` command

Comment: @AidenTooMLG - check the answers here - http://superuser.com/questions/378967/change-background-of-a-windows-7-machine-using-registry

Comment: @npocmaka Check my modified script and tell me if it is working for you or not ?

Comment: @npocmaka That script errors out on line 28, the `windows.resizeTo` line..

Comment: @Kappa - did you saved this with `.bat` extension?

Comment: @Kappa - I've tested this on win7 and win10 both working :-\

Comment: interesting... well it's okay, i've had weird errors which people couldn't reproduce before...